# Correct highlighting with Qt custom delegates

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am making a table control that displays some additional text data apart from those in `DisplayRole` of its model. In all other respects, text and cell display should be identical. What I am having trouble with is correct display of highlighted cells.

I am currently using the following code:

```cpp
void MatchDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
         painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());
    painter->save();
    QString str = qvariant_cast<QString>(index.data())+ "\n";
    str  += QString::number(qvariant_cast<float>(index.data(Qt::UserRole)));
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        painter->setBrush(option.palette.highlightedText());
    else
        painter->setBrush(qvariant_cast<QBrush>(index.data(Qt::ForegroundRole)));
   
    painter->drawText(option.rect, qvariant_cast<int>(index.data(Qt::TextAlignmentRole)), str);
    painter->restore();
}
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image: highlighted cell]

The text color is wrong, there is no dashing line around the cell, and when the control loses focus, the cell remains blue instead of becoming light gray like drawn by default cells do.

How should painting code be changed to fix those issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `drawControl` will take care of drawing the dashed line (let Qt take care of it internally) when selected.

> Fixed (dashed line, text color and multiline) while selecting cell.

[image]

```cpp
void MatchDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{         

    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);

    const QWidget *widget = option.widget;
    QString str = qvariant_cast<QString>(index.data())+ "\n";
     str  += QString::number(qvariant_cast<float>(index.data(Qt::UserRole)));
       opt.text = "";
    //option
    QStyle *style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();


    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
    {
        // Whitee pen while selection
        painter->setPen(Qt::white);
        painter->setBrush(option.palette.highlightedText());
        // This call will take care to draw, dashed line while selecting
        style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, widget);
    }
    else
    {
        painter->setPen(QPen(option.palette.foreground(), 0));
        painter->setBrush(qvariant_cast<QBrush>(index.data(Qt::ForegroundRole)));
    }

    painter->drawText(option.rect, qvariant_cast<int>(index.data(Qt::TextAlignmentRole)), str);
}
```

Comment: Updates for this code snippet in 2022 with Qt6. The line `if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)` can be changed to `int highlightedFlags = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Selected | QStyle::State_Active;
if ((option.state & highlightedFlags) == highlightedFlags)` to better reflect loss of application focus and multiple cell selection. `QPalette::foreground()` has been deprecated and removed in favour of `QPalette::windowText()`. When drawing the text I modified the rect as `option.rect.adjusted(3, 3, -3, -3)` to match other cell painting (hacky but not sure how else to do this).